# Assembly intel x86 which addresses can be used to define arguments

Tags: c, assembly, nasm

Which memory points can I actually use?
I have this assembly code to power(a,b) by recursion:

```
 int power(int x, int y);                                                  *
;*****************************************************************************
%define x [ebp+8]
%define y [ebp+12]
power:
    push ebp    
    mov ebp, esp

    mov eax, y  ;move y into eax
    cmp eax, 0  ;compare y to 0
    jne l10;    ;if not equal, jump to l10  
    mov eax, 1  ;move 1 into eax
    jmp l20;    ;jump to l20, the leave, ret label

l10:
    mov eax, y ; move y into eax
    sub eax, 1 ; y-1
    push eax   ; push y-1 onto stack
    mov ebx, x ; move x into ebx
    push ebx   ; push x onto stack
    call power ; call power/recursion
    add esp, 8 ; add 8 to stack(4*2) for the two vars
    imul eax, x ; multiply the returned value from call by x

l20:
    leave ; leave
    ret   ;ret
```

It's coded straight from this c code:

```
int power_c(int x, int y) {
    if (y == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return power_c(x, y - 1)*x;
    }
}
```

The asm code works perfectly, any suggested adjustments would be great, I'm still new to assembly. My question is, which addresses can I actually use to define arguments? Here, I have two, and I use:

```
%define x [ebp+8]
%define y [ebp+12]
```

If I have more, do I just increase it? Lets say all are ints, 4bytes, like so?

```
%define x [ebp+8]
%define y [ebp+12]
%define z [ebp+16]
%define a [ebp+20]
%define b [ebp+24]
```

I've hit a snag with code where I need to define more arguments, I just can't figure this out, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: x and y are function arguments, not local variables.  They are treated differently.

Comment: I see. I never thought they were any different. Thank you for clarifying this.

Comment: @AShelly this here, https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Functions_and_Stack_Frames, explained it. Change in question, check edit.

Comment: To reserve stack space for locals below EBP, `sub esp, 24` or whatever at the start of your function, and reverse that before returning.

Comment: hint: use meaningful names for labels.  `jmp epilogue` tells you everything that `jmp l20;    ;jump to l20, the leave, ret label` does, and doesn't need a comment.  Or the comment can explain *why* you're taking that jump there.  Similarly, `mov eax, 1  ;move 1 into eax` is a useless comment.  Resist the temptation to explain things you just learned.  A comment like `return 1 because ...` would be much more useful.

Comment: @PeterCordes and to call each local I'd use [ebp-4], [ebp-8], ect?

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks, I'll keep that in mind. I was wondering, if I were to pass a local variable to a call, say 
`mov eax, [ebp-4]`,
`push eax`,
`call function`,
what goes here?
`add esp, 4`? is it any different from sending an argument?
Sorry, I have a lot of question about assembly, and no one to answer them

Comment: @AShelly Technically, arguments are local variables. You are allowed to modify them, for example. The distinction between them is, the called function allocates room for local variables below the return address, the caller allocates and initialiizes space for arguments before making the call, above the return address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Arguments** are passed on the stack - the caller is responsible for pushing them. The space is already reserved when your function starts. If you changed your prototype to `power_c(int x, int y, int z)`, then z would be at `[ebp+16]`.

**Local Variables** (or automatics) are your responsibility. The standard way is to subtract the space you need from `esp`, as @Peter Cordes mentions in the comments.  So to create variable `a` and `b`, you would do:

```
sub esp, 8
%define a [ebp+4]
%define b [ebp-8]
```

Note that at this point `ebp` == `esp+8`. We define the variables relative to `ebp`, not `esp`, so that you can continue to use push and pop instructions (which change the stack pointer).   Remember to set `esp` back to `ebp` (`mov esp, ebp`) before you exit the function, so that the return address is found correctly.

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Calling_Conventions#Standard_C_Calling_Conventions explains this scheme fairly well.